# How can I simultaneously in one "click" event delete two documents from two collection in my cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

i just want to delete multiple documents from two different collections(hive and entry).  how should i do this?  with two promises or how?

my below code works but the moment I add "location.reload()" anywhere, only the clicked hive is deleted.  the page just doesn't work with this refresh function...

please help...  thanks in advance!

```
    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      let id = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
      var x = confirm("Deleting a hive will delete all its records.  Click 'Ok' to delete and 'Cancel' to return.");
      if(x){
// delete clicked hive
        db.collection('hive').doc(id).delete()
          .then(function () {
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
          })
// delete all entries from within clicked hive
        var deleteEntry = db.collection('entry').where('hive_id', "==", id);
        deleteEntry.get()
          .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            doc.ref.delete()
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
          })
      }else{
      }
    })
```

the above approach might be completely wrong and not clean...so i will just type my needed results here...

after clicking deleteBtn and confirming the delete, the clicked hive should be deleted and all entry records from that hive should also be deleted.  the page needs to refresh and show that the hive is gone.  (note that all entry records have the same hive will have the hives id as property)

THANKS!

Comment: Does your code work the way you expect?  If so, no need to change anything.  If not, please describe what the problem is.

Comment: yes it does work to a point.  the problem is like addressed, i want it to refresh automattically so i add "location.reload()" but this somehow messes up the delete of my "entry"...dont know what the problem is here...

Comment: Look into using `Promise.all()` to create a new promise that resolves when all the other promises are resolved.  Use that new promise to reload the page.

Comment: alright thanks, will look into that...never worked with them in parallel though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a typical async problem. Try this: Add the delete code for entry collection inside the promise of deleting hive code.

```
   deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   let id = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
   var x = confirm("Deleting a hive will delete all its records.  Click 'Ok' to   delete and 'Cancel' to return.");
   if(x){
   // delete clicked hive
    db.collection('hive').doc(id).delete()
      .then(function () {

   // delete all entries from within clicked hive
    var deleteEntry = db.collection('entry').where('hive_id', "==", id);
    deleteEntry.get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.ref.delete()
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      })

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      })

  }else{
  }
})
```

Comment: i tried it and it didnt work. but it worked right after i but another .then after delete().  but thanks!!!